# Mongo Aggregate Query on large data using java driver?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I am using spring batch framework for processing large amount of data in mongo db and storing again in mongo db

The code is as follows :

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(           
            project("field1")                   
                //projection on few fields                  
            group("field1")             
                //group opeartion               
            project(                
                // again project on grouped result              
            )
).withOptions(newAggregationOptions().allowDiskUse(true).build());

AggregationResults<BeanName> agreatiR = dbTemplate.aggregate(agg,collectionName,BeanName.class);
```

For less data (I have tested on 100k), the aggregate framework works fine but for 2M it gives exception of 16 MB limit exceeds.

I do not want to use $out operation as firstly it is not required and also there didn't seems any API to use $out in spring data mongo

Also i have read of returning cursors which will allow the exceeded size limit but again there isn't seems to be any spring data mongo API supporting that.

Mongo DB version : 2.6

Mongo Driver Version : 3.2.0

Comment: for large collection, try to split your processing in 100k records in order to make it works.

Comment: I wish if could get a solution for working on same data without splitting

Comment: can you provide code for itemprocessor? How much data are you processing at once?

Comment: The code I have mentioned above is a code in Tasklet. I am processing on 2M data

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you're trying to commit 2M at once. This is bad because load all beans in memory.

You should use `commit-interval` in order to reduice this huge job. Have you done that?

```
<tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="500"/>
    </tasklet>
```

[see configuring a step in official doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html)

Comment: I am not using chunk rather using tasklet to take whole data. This is because there is no other way to read the data one by one in chunk